# Sitecore branch template standard values

Tags: templates, sitecore, branch, sitecore7.2

Is it possible to update all the items based on a branch template when the template is changed?
Basically, I've created a branch template with a child item. Then I created a couple of pages based on that branch template. Now if I add a new child item to the branch template I'd like to have that new child item added to the pages.

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 Update-5

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I am afraid it is not possible to do out of the box in Sitecore. Branch templates are used to create initial structure with initial values. But when you will change your branch template you could not propagate this changes on all items that were create using it.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Maybe I could extend the save action/pipeline so when a branch template is saved I go through the tree and update the items? Sounds like a long shot.

Comment: @Snapper: You'd probably have more luck modifying the StandardValuesProvider, so that it provides the value from the branch (available through item.BranchId). Haven't tried this, but should be possible.